# Why is this type assertion from bson.M necessary?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have the following code, making use of go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver libraries:

```
updateMap := bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "dateAdded": primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now()),
    },
}
if len(alias) > 0 {
    // I don't see how this type assertion is necessary
    updateMap["$set"].(map[string]interface{})["alias"] = alias
}
```

If I do:

```
updateMap["$addFields"].(map[string]map[string]string)["alias"] = alias
```

it doesn't compile. The compiler already knows that updateMap is of type bson.M which is a `map[string]interface{}`. How does asserting that it really is a `map[string]interface{}` doing anything useful for the compiler? I thought it would want to know what kind of interface it actually is, but apparently it doesn't want me to do that.

What is going on here?

edit: and of course, it should be noted that without a type assertion here, it doesn't compile:

> invalid operation: cannot index updateMap["$addFields"] (map index expression of type interface{})

Comment: Your confusing probably stems from a wrong understanding of `interface{}`. Go is statically typed and `interface{}` means `interface{}` not "any type". `interface{}` is a type like string or uint16, it's not a placeholder for "any type". If a map contains `interface{}` this `interface{}` is literally baked into the maps type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bson.M` is defined as an alias of `primitive.M`, which is [defined](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.9.1/bson/primitive#M) as `type M map[string]interface{}` (that is, a non-alias type). The problem is that `updateMap["$set"]` is a `bson.M`, which is a distinct type compared to `map[string]interface{}`. So your type assertion would have to be to `bson.M` instead, for example:

```golang
updateMap["$set"].(bson.M)["alias"] = alias
```

[Runnable example in Go playground.](https://go.dev/play/p/MiP7IvQCJlS)